# How to decipher this Q/KDB code

Tags: kdb

I need to understand this code.

```
raze(handle1, handle2, handle3)@\:({.myqueries.select_from_all[`some_table] . (a;b;c;();();0b);p1,p2;`})
```

Basically, the idea is to select from three databases data from the same table.

What does `@\:` do in this case? Why do we have `{}` inside `()`?

What does the `.` mean after `` select_from_all[`some_table] ``?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code you've supplied, looks like there may be something missing - I'll run you through the expected form of what it looks like the code is doing:

```
raze(listOfHandles)@\:({[x;y] funcUsingXandY};arg0;arg1)

where:
      listOfHandles - a list of handles to remote processes
      @\: - apply the right hand side to each item in the left hand side list
      ({[x;y] funcUsingXandY};arg0;arg1) - this sends a function definition (lambda) + args for the function, to be executed on each of the handles.
```

An example (assumes there are processes listening on localhost, port 7070 and 7071):

```
q) handle1:hopen 7070;
q) handle2:hopen 7071;
q) raze(handle1,handle2)@\:({[x;y] enlist(.z.p; x+y)}; 39;3)
    2014.08.23D14:11:15.452611000 42
    2014.08.23D14:11:15.452847000 42
```

In the above example, we execute the function `{[x;y] enlist(.z.p; x+y)}` with args `(39;3)` on each of the remote handles `handle1` and `handle2` -- we get a response of current time (`.z.p`) & sum of the two args in our response for each handle. The `raze` joins the results returned from each handle into a single list (in your example, it looks like the function is returning a table - in this case, `raze` would join the list of tables return from the handles, into a single table)

**Edit:** I missed the part in your question regarding `.` -- the . allows you to apply a list of arguments to a function taking multiple args - for example:

```
q)plus:{[x;y] x+y}
q)plus . (4;5)
    9
```

For more info, see:

- http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/i_o#Message_Format
- http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/functions#Adverbs
- http://code.kx.com/wiki/JB:QforMortals2/functions#Functional_Forms_of_Amend
- http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/DotSymbol